# MS LightSwitch - How to remove/filter items from VisualCollection<T>

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Microsoft LightSwitch with the Silverlight client. I need to remove items from a VisualCollection. I could not see anything like a Delete() or Remove() method. There are only RemoveSelected or DeleteSelected, but I need to delete/remove multiple lines.

I have a collection and the user will mark a checkbox to select the entities, then press a button. Then I have to show only the marked entities in the next step. But I am unable to filter this VisualCollection. Also, as it is readonly, I cannot reassign the filtered collection to overwrite this.